# Where is a good place to put your online scripts in private?

Tags: file

Right now everything I code/script goes into random folders on my hard drive. Very disorganized. Is there a place online where I can upload everything to a central location and have it be private / not publicly accessible? Or do I just need to get a web server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) is free and offers private repositories

[GitHub](https://github.com/) also has free public repos but you need to pay for private ones

Comment: Why would anyone choose GitHub if Bitbucket is free? Does GitHub offer anything more than Bitbucket?

Comment: GitHub is widely used by professional programmers. It is also the one that OpenSource projects use to show their code all over the web.

Answer (score -1):

The Github "micro" plan might be what you need.  Or free dropbox or bob accounts.